# Android: Open Messenger chat view with specific person

Tags: android, facebook

There are few questions about opening a messenger chat with a specif person, and the answer to all of them is not possible.

But the Facebook app does this. When clicking on a friend icon at the top right corner and picking one of the friends, it opens a Messenger-chat with that person.
**So how do they do it**? I have been trying to find some intent they pass, but I saw nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://m.me/"+"FacebookId"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research came up with this:

```
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/" + "myapp"));
    startActivity(mIntent);
```

Hopefully, it would save your time.